# Correct _construct initialization

Tags: php, constructor

How can I correctly initialize `$PDOgen` and `$PDO`, where `$PDO` is generated by

`$this->PDOgen->getPDOName('db_name')`

and both should be available in `SomeModel` class as `$this->PDO`, `$this->PDOgen`?

```
abstract class Model {
    protected $PDO;
    protected $PDOgen;

    public function _construct(){
        $this->PDOgen = new \Namespace\PDOgen(); //edited2 line;
    }
}

class SomeModel extends Model{
    public function _construct(){
           $this->PDO =  $this->PDOgen->getPDOName('db_name_for_this_model'); //edited2 line;   
    }

    public function fun(){
          $this->PDOgen-> ...
          $this->PDO-> ...      
    }
}

class PDOgen {
...
    public function getPDOName($db_name) {
        return getPDO( ... ); 
    }
}
```

Edited:
I simply lost one _ in constructor.
Should be __construct instead of _construct;

Edited 2: Should be like here. Before finding lost sign, i had no idea what should be in constructor, because nothing worked.

Comment: Seems like you should be injecting `PDOGen` and `$db_name` into `SomeModel` and then assigning it to the corresponding property in the constructor.  Then assign `$this->PDO = $this->PDOgen->getPDOName($db_name);`    But I'm interested to see the responses also, because I think you're trying to do something I haven't learned yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply lost one _ in constructor. Should be __construct instead of _construct;

Comment: I'm confused.  How do the properties of Model become an object?  Where is `PDOgen->getPDOName()` getting `$db_name`?

Comment: Like in edited 2. I wrote this topic in in late night, after hours of work, so it could not be clear. Thus, i answered myself for this problem.